# gridstack.js - how to strech columns to fit width?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use gridstack ( https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js ) in a configuration of just 5 columns, but the problem is the default is 12 columns, and when I configure to only 5, these 5 columns are squeezed to the left and I have the space of 7 unusable columns on the right.

I would like to use all the screen width to acomodate these columns. Could you help me with the solution? I used `options = { width: 5 }` and the recommendations on https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#change-grid-width , but with no success.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated CSS rules for your grid? You need to define new rules for it.

Please check out the documentation https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#change-grid-width

Answer (score 0):

```
GridStack.init({
  column: 9
})
```

Also you will need to import both these CSS files:

```
node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css // normal Gridstack CSS
node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-extra.min.css // needed if not using 12 columns
```